How to install openstacksdk in Visual Studio Code
I'm trying to install openstacksdk in VSC but it's giving me an error. I've also installed Build Tools for Visual Studio but it's giving me the same error. I have updated pip and wheel**.**
(python 3.11)
pip install openstacksdk 
error:
Building wheels for collected packages: netifaces
  Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'netifaces' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-311\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.11.0 "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcnetifaces.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-311\Release\netifaces.obj
      netifaces.c
      creating C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g8bpg1nl\netifaces_7467204b6f8147a795de1588afa0bf5f\build\lib.win32-cpython-311
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\libs" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\PCbuild\win32" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x86" ws2_32.lib iphlpapi.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_netifaces build\temp.win32-cpython-311\Release\netifaces.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-cpython-311\netifaces.cp311-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-cpython-311\Release\netifaces.cp311-win_amd64.lib
         Creation of the library build\temp.win32-cpython-311\Release\netifaces.cp311-win_amd64.lib e dell'oggetto build\temp.win32-cpython-311\Release\netifaces.cp311-win_amd64.exp
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddIntConstant unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyLong_FromLong unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyExc_MemoryError unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetFromWindowsErr unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyDict_SetItemString unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyUnicode_FromWideChar unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyExc_ValueError unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddStringConstant unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp___Py_FalseStruct unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp___Py_Dealloc unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyModule_AddObject unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyList_New unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyModule_Create2 unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyList_Append unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyDict_SetItem unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyDict_New unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyErr_NoMemory unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyDict_GetItemString unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyExc_OSError unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyDict_GetItem unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyObject_IsTrue unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyTuple_Pack unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp___Py_TrueStruct unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyUnicode_FromString unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyObject_Size unresolved
      netifaces.obj : error LNK2001: external symbol __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple unresolved
      build\lib.win32-cpython-311\netifaces.cp311-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 27 external unresolved
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
  Running setup.py clean for netifaces
Failed to build netifaces
ERROR: Could not build wheels for netifaces, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I updated pip and wheel, then I installed Build Tools.

I installed a old version for openstacksdk and then I updated it with this command: pip install --upgrade openstacksdk.

You may need to install Cmake with the following command and upgrade setuptools at the same time
pip install Cmake
pip install --upgrade setuptools

